# EigenFace implementation: in Java using OpenCV3

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans-8, face-recognition, opencv3.0

I want to recognize faces in real time through a webcam.I have worked till detecting a face through webcam,but I am having trouble in implementing eigen face algorithm in Java (Netbeans).

I have achieved face detection using following code :-

```
private DaemonThread myThread = null;
int count = 0;
VideoCapture webSource = null;

Mat frame = new Mat();
MatOfByte mem = new MatOfByte();
CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(ScannerGUI.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath().substring(1));
MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();


class DaemonThread implements Runnable
{
protected volatile boolean runnable = false;

@Override
public  void run()
{
    synchronized(this)
    {
        while(runnable)
        {
            if(webSource.grab())
            {
            try
                    {
                        webSource.retrieve(frame);
            //Highgui.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);
                        Graphics g=jPanel1.getGraphics();
                        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(frame, faceDetections);

                        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) 
                       {  Imgproc.rectangle(frame, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),new Scalar(0, 255, 0),2);
                        }

                        Imgcodecs.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);
            Image im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray()));
            BufferedImage buff = (BufferedImage) im;
            if (g.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() -150 , 0, 0, buff.getWidth(), buff.getHeight(), null))

            if(runnable == false)
                        {
                System.out.println("Going to wait()");
                this.wait();
            }
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
                     {
            System.out.println("Error");
                     }
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Now I want to first first save the detected face in eigen faces and then recognize this face.

Can someone please help me through this I have thoroughly searched online for the Eigen face implementation in Java but couldn't able to find anything useful.

Please help me through this as I am new in OpenCV and this My project for College.

Comment: OpenCV already provide [eigenface implementation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/face/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#eigenfaces). I don't know if the the java wrapper supports it, but you can always call native C++ code.

Comment: it's all in the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/org/opencv/core/Core.html#PCACompute(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat))

Answer (score 0):

To build the OpenCV from source with contrib modules (which contain the org.opencv.face package for Java), see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224468/opencv-3-0-0-face-recognizer-with-java/40138825#40138825).

After building the JAR with contrib modules, you can instantiate an EigenFaceRecognizer like this:

> FaceRecognizer model = org.opencv.face.Face.createEigenFaceRecognizer();