# OpenCv 3.0.0 Face Recognizer with Java

Tags: face-recognition, opencv3.0

I'm writing this post to ask how I can use Face Recognizer in a JAVA project.
I'm trying to generate with cmake the jar file of opencv3.0.0.0 with all its contribs, but the resulted generated jar  contains only standard modules. I've also tried to use the 2.4.11 version but i can't realize how to make a concrete instance of the face recognizer class.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for this?

Comment: Hi did you solve the problem, I also have the same problem with opencv 3.1 which does not have FaceRecognizer.java class

Answer (score 1):

The one part that is a bit tricky to find in any documentation is about editing the CMakeLists.txt for the contrib modules.  It seems that is the only part you are missing, but I have included the full step-by-step process below for others.

1. Download/clone opencv repository found [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv)
2. Download/clone opencv_contrib repository found [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib)
3. Go to opencv_contrib/modules/face and edit CMakeLists.txt
4. Find the line that begins with ocv_define_module and add "java" so that it looks something like this:

   > ocv_define_module(face opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_objdetect WRAP python java)
5. Compile opencv with contrib modules [as normal](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html), i.e. adding the appropriate parameters to cmake as follows:

   > cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<path to opencv_contrib>
6. The JAR built in the bin/ folder will now contain the org.opencv.face package